# Postgresql parse xml with missing keys

Tags: xml, postgresql, xpath

Word of notice: I'm completely new to xml data type and methods in Postresql.

I have a table with N rows, each one having a xml collection.

The xml per row has a collection of consecutive sequences key/value, such as

Row 1:

```
<key>foo</key><string>foo_value_1</string><key>bar</key><string>bar_value_1</string><key>baz</key><string>baz_value_1</string>
```

Row 2:

```
<key>foo</key><string>foo_value_2</string><key>baz</key><string>baz_value_2</string>
```

Notice that keys are always sorted in the xml-rows, sorted as in foo,bar,baz; but some keys might be absent (e.g.: bar is absent in the second row)

I'd need to retrieve this by means of a SQL select:

```
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|     foo     |     bar     |     baz     |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| foo_value_1 | bar_value_1 | baz_value_1 |
| foo_value_2 | NULL        | baz_value_2 |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Sample fiddle:

```
with 
sample as
(
    select '<key>foo</key><string>foo_value_1</string><key>bar</key><string>bar_value_1</string><key>baz</key><string>baz_value_1</string>'::xml    as xmlcol
    union all
    select '<key>foo</key><string>foo_value_2</string><key>baz</key><string>baz_value_2</string>'::xml                                              as xmlcol
)
select  --foo?
        --bar?
        --baz?
from    sample
```

Any help shall be much appreciated!

Comment: I don't see any simple ways to do that in SQL. You would be basically trying to write procedural code in SQL, at which point you might as well write it in a procedural language.

Comment: If you wanted to do that in SQL, it could roughly look like this: convert every XML tag into a row (tag name, tag content), group every consecutive 2 rows, select first tag's content as key and second as value, and finally group values by key. Then you would need to transpose rows to columns. Doesn't look like a good use of SQL to me.